# Can someone explain to me this list behaviour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
>>> lista=[[12,13],[0,1]]
>>> lista
[[12, 13], [0, 1]]
>>> lista[0]=lista[1]
>>> lista
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
>>> lista[0][0]+=10
>>> lista
[[10, 1], [10, 1]]
```

What i expect to happen is to last output be like:

```
 [[10, 1], [0, 1]]
```

but instead it behaves as if I typed:

```
lista[0][0]+=10 
lista[1][0]+=10
```

instead of just

```
lista[0][0]+=10
```

i think the problem is with this part:

```
lista[0]=lista[1]
```

because when i type instead

```
 lista[0]=list(lista[1])
```

it works just fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because lists in python are *mutable*

Essentially when you do:

`lista[0]=lista[1]`

You are saying let the index 0 point to the same location in memory that the index 1 is pointing to. So, we essentially have the same pointer at index 0 and 1 pointing to the same object.

**A visual explanation:**

Picture the list:

`list_a = [1, 2, 3]`

If we set `list_b` equal to `list_a` (by doing `list_b = list_a`) then we get can picture the lists as:
[image: Python lists sharing the same objects in memory]

As you can see from above, the objects (the integers in `list_a`) are shared with `list_b`. Thus, if we change a value in `list_b` like so:

`list_b[0] = 100` then `list_a` and `list_b` will look like `[100, 2, 3]`

Thus, if you apply this concept to your 2D list (table) you can picture we can observe that you are **editing the same object in memory**. In order to get your expected output you need to copy the list so that it points to its own unique object in memory.

Comment: This is not "due to a concept known as mutability", just to the fact - that you otherwise explain - that in Python assignment doesn't copy the assigned object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `lista[0]=lista[1]`. Assignment makes to objects refer to *the same* object, it does not copy them. eg, for two standalone lists

```
l1 = [1,2]
l0 = l1
l0[0] = 2 # print l1 after that
```

The exact same thing happens in your case.

However, `list(lista[1])` creates *a new list* from the elements of `lista[1]`, and assigns this new list to `lista[0]`. So now, they are two *different objects*, which happen to have the same values. If you change one, nothing happens to the other.

It would be the same if you used any other copying method, eg

```
lista[0] = lista[1][:]
```